# When renaming a subset of columns in R dataframe, the first column data is duplicated

Tags: r

I have a data frame of 1530 columns, the first 800 of which I want to subset to have a common name and the last 730 of which I want to subset to have a common name. My attempts to rename the first subset have been `colnames(dataframe)[1:800] <- c("NonNorm")` and `colnames(dataframe)[1:800] <- rep("NonNorm", 800)`.

However, when I view the altered data frame, all of the values in the rows of the first column have been duplicated across all of the columns through 800. Why is this happening and how do I preserve the original values while changing the column names?

Comment: `colnames(dataframe) <- c(rep("CommonName", 800), rep("SecondCommonName", 730))`

Comment: Thanks, I think it is an issue of how I was viewing the dataframe after the alteration. But this is a succinct solution, cheers.

Comment: It is better to have a unique column name, so, `make.unique(rep(c("CommonName", "SecondCommonName"), c(800, 730)))`